# Feeds not working on Technorati

Tags: feeds

I submitted my site to Technorati but they prompt me that can not read from my [feed url](http://feeds.feedburner.com/StartupsAndFinance). I see it to be fine and it worked fine on other sites. Any ideas if there is a special requirement for technorati?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would contact Technorati and let them know you have a w3c valid feed why cant they read your feed

http://validator.w3.org/appc/

You are submitting your Feed URL to them right http://www.startupsandfinance.com/feed/ and not your feedburner URL?

Did you put the confirmation code into your feeds?

Comment: I was giving them my feedburner url.

Comment: The problem was with the confirmation code.Thanks.

Comment: Cool glad I could help